# Currency Conversion in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want convert Bitcoin into user country currency.I know about Exchange Rate API https://blockchain.info/ticker but it does not provide rates for India, Pakistan, United Arab Emirates etc.

Answer (score 0):

Currency Layer supports more than 168 currencies and it has a free plan, included Bitcoin, AED  United Arab Emirates Dirham, INR Indian Rupee, PKR Pakistani Rupee... Here's the list:

https://currencylayer.com/currencies

Some of the gems you could try:

https://github.com/phlegx/money-currencylayer-bank

https://github.com/askuratovsky/currencylayer